# How to automatically add media to new row/column

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I am building a children web game using PHP and MySQLi and I am now making a page having pictures and audios sorted in a table having the picture displayed on the left side and the audio on the right as so:
[image]

what I want to do is, I want to add a button where user can choose another picture and audio and after selected, it will automatically add the media in a new row like so: [image] I have found a way to add new rows but it will dissapear when I reload the page. Code

```html
<body>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Add new row</button>

 <table border="1" align="center" id="table1">
  <tr>
   <td><img src="images/croc.png" width="200"></td>
   <td><audio controls src="music/crocodile.mp3"></audio>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><img src="images/caution.png" width="200"></td>
   <td><audio controls src="music/crocodile.mp3"></audio>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

May I know how to browse for file and automatically, permanently add user's choice of media into new row of the table in the webpage?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: added @OscarZarrus

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a note: you're adding your table rows with `javascript` which runs on the client side in your browser. If you reload the page, you'll get the same old copy from your server. So at first, you'll have to decide if you want to render and extend your table on the server (and use `php`) or you use some sort of client side scripting to build your table.

Comment: How do I make it that the client can add new row to add the items of their choice and permanently save the newly added row ( + the items the client added) on the server also ? @ventiseis

Comment: I'm no expert in `php`, but one common way to do this is to have the server define a `REST api` which allows you to list / modify the row collection by async http requests to the server. You can code this all by yourself, ore use one of many libraries for that. Example: `jquery` is a popular example which helps you with client document modification (adding rows) after reading the rows from your server sent in `json` format. On the server, you'll need some kind of storage (for example `mysql`) and middleware code to read stored data from the database to send it to the client as `json` strings.